# removing/disabling LED lights in kids shoes

Tags: shoes, safety, light

Some kids sneakers have built-in LED lights which light up when you walk on them.

For various reasons, a person would like to permanently disable the lights.

Is there a safe way to do so?

Asking around, a few people mentioned microwaving the shoes for a few seconds.

But this seems dangerous, especially since there's a battery inside the shoe which causes it to light up.
Has anyone tried microwaving it? Is it indeed safe? Did it stop the shoe from lighting up?

The goal is to get the shoe to stop lighting up, without damaging the shoe itself.

There are some people [here](https://www.homeownershub.com/maintenance/how-do-you-turn-off-the-lights-on-a-kid-s-sneaker-712065-1.htm) suggesting the microwave option, and also soaking the shoes in water etc. But these all seem like theoretical options, which may damage the shoes themselves. If anyone has actually tried out any of these options, and can confirm that they work without damaging the shoes, that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Hi Binyomin, Welcome to Lifehacks. Rather than destroying (wholly or partially) the shoes, consider not getting the product. Microwaves will create a problem with metallic components so the corrosive materials that may result by melting the circuit in ignorance is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Thanks @Stan. I was asked this by a friend who received the shoes as a gift, in a way where they can't return it to the store. And your comment about the microwave sounds very legit, which is why it's hard to believe people are recommending it. That's why I'm curious to see if anyone has actually done it in a safe way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to disable the LED lights in children's (or adult's) shoes is to not plug the charger into the battery and let the battery go dead.

The battery can only hold a couple of hours of charge for lighting up your way.

Good luck.

Comment: rechargeable sneakers? I never saw that before. These are the "old fashioned" kind, with a battery that lasts months on it's own and basically dies when the shoe itself is worn out.

Comment: @Binyomin How many years ago was this given as a gift? Ask your "friend" to look at the printed matter that comes in the box with the shoes. Lost? Contact the manufacturer's marketing department and you'll get details. No? Lift the insole and disconnect the power cord from the source to the load.

Comment: I will pass this on. They told me the didn't see anything about a charger, but I'll mention this part about the insoles to them and see what they say. Their story made sense to me, since my toddler daughter has a pair, which was purchased in 2018 and started to be worn in late 2019, that has lasted for months with no charge.

Answer (score 1):

Just pull out the insoles carefully. The wires for the lights will be exposed. Cut them and put the insoles back in. I just did it yesterday, it worked without baking or soaking the shoes.

Answer (score -1):

1. Puts shoes on
2. Put fast-paced music on
3. Dance around until battery dies

Comment: With a battery that can last for months of normal use, you will be very tired and having to stop long before the power is all used.